# how to preserve validation set in caret for hyperparameter tuning instead of cross validation?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, r-caret

```
trainControl(method=)
```

I have a large time series dataset, and I would like to split into training,validation and testing set. However, I couldn't find the setting for prespecified validation set in caret trainControl for hyperparameter tuning. I don't wish to use cross validation in such case.

I wish further use it in with the train function to fit my model.

```
fit<-train(...)
```

Comment: Hi Grace, welcome to SO. It's not yet very clear what you need, maybe you can provide example data and some code to better highlight your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. 

If you're not using CV for hyper-parameter selection, whatt are you using instead? What kind of model are you fitting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.